# Chrome extension communication popup.js and background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, dom-events

I am busy developing my very first Chrome extension. I am having trouble communicating between popup.js and background.js. The errors I am getting are the following:

In code:

**1. Background.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  // Background


  chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting === "GetURL") {
      var tabURL = "Not set yet";
      chrome.tabs.query({
        active: true
      }, function (tabs) {
        if (tabs.length === 0) {
          sendResponse({});
          return;
        }
        tabURL = tabs[0].url;
        sendResponse({
          navURL: tabURL
        });
      });
    }
  });


});
```

**2.popup.js**

```
   ((function () {


  function getCurrentTabUrl(callback) {

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      // https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query
      var queryInfo = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
      };

      chrome.tabs.query(queryInfo, function (tabs) {
        if (callback(tabs[0].url)) {
          return resolve();
        } else {
          return reject();
        }
      });
    });
  }



  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {


    var callback = function getCurrentTab(tab) {
      if (tab == "https://www.facebook.com/") {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }

    }


    getCurrentTabUrl(callback).then(function () {
      alert('on facebook');
      $('.section').hide();

    }, function () {
      alert('not on facebook');
    });


    $('.menuItem').hide();

    $('.menuItem:first').show();

    jQuery('.navitem').on('click', function () {

      var value = $(this).html().toLocaleLowerCase();
      jQuery('.menuItem').hide();
      jQuery('#' + value).show();

    });


    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function () {


      alert("changed");

      function getURL() {
        chrome.runtime.sendMessage("ididididid", {
            greeting: "GetURL"
          },
          function (response) {
            tabURL = response.navURL;
            $("#tabURL").text(tabURL);
          });
      }

      alert(getURL());


    });
  });



})());
```

My manifest.json looks like this:

```
    {

      "name": "FaceBlock",
      "description": "This extention gets rid of unwanted content on Facebook like sponsored posts, adds or annoying suggestions. The content you wish to see is enlarged for a better and richer social experience.",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "manifest_version": 2,
      "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": [
        "http://*.facebook.com/*", "https://*.facebook.com/*"],
          "js": ["background.js"],
          "run_at": "document_end",
          "all_frames": true
    }],
      "options_page": "options.html",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html",
        "default_title": "Click me!"
    },
      "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://www.facebook.com/*",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "storage"
  ],
      "background": {
        "scripts": ["js/jquery.min.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "options_ui": {
        // Required.
        "page": "popup.html",
        // Recommended.
        "chrome_style": true
          // Not recommended; only provided for backwards compatibility,
          // and will be unsupported in a future version of Chrome (TBD).
          //"open_in_tab": true
      },
      "web_accessible_resources": [
    
    "images/faceblock.jpg",
    "images/seigaiha.png",
    "js/popup.js",
    "icon.png",
    "js/options.js",
    "css/popup.css",
    "popup.html",
    "options.html"
  ]
    }
```

The following is my background.html:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>background</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

And finally, a part of my popup.html:

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Facebook AdBlock</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/popup.css" />
  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
  <script src="js/background.js"></script>
  <script src="js/options.js"></script>
  
</head>

<body>
  <div id="popup">

    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">

      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navitem">Posts</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navitem">Sidebar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navitem">Privacy</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger navitem">General</button>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-cog navitem" style="margin-top: -2px;"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Does somebody know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: 1. See [the architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch): background page is a separate document but you include its script in content_scripts and popup, which is wrong. 2. your screenshot shows `file://` paths are being used, but the extensions must be installed on chrome://extensions page and invoked via browser UI, not as plain pages from the local disk. 3. Instead of screenshot include the relevant code as text in the question. 4. The question doesn't contain the code that uses addListener

Comment: Okay thanks for your feedback i'll see what I can do!